# css inline-block vs float

Tags: html, css-float, css

I'm doing some tests on `float` and `inline-block` and i've noticed there is a difference between them.

As you can see from [**THIS EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kwrtD), that if I use `display:inline-block` the divs have a little margin between them but if I use `float:left` it works as expected.

Please note that i'm using Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0.

Is it because I'm doing something wrong or is this the way `inline-block` behaves (in that case it is not very reliable).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>How padding/margin affect floats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS (without reset)**

```
#wrap{
  width: 600px;
    margin:auto;
}

.square{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the parent element `font-size: 0;`.

Then, set the `font-size` of the children to `font-size: 12px` (or whatever size your design dictates), like this:

```
#wrap{
    font-size:0;
}
.square{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> I'm doing some tests on float and inline-block and i've noticed there
>   is a difference between them.

Whatever resource gave you the implication that they might **not** be the same is misleading. They are [completely different things](http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block).

> the divs have a little margin between them

That's not a `margin`. That's a space resulting from the line-breaks between the `div`s in the HTML. One solution would be to just remove the line-breaks, another would be to set `font-size: 0` on the containing element (thus causing the spaces not to be rendered).

Note that if you use the second method, you'll need to set another `font-size` on the inner `div`s, otherwise the text inside them won't be rendered.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware the line-breaks are being treated as spaces.

Comment: @ftom2 Yep, that's always the case with HTML. Similarly, tabs are rendered as spaces.

Answer (score 7):

It is because of spaces. If you set `font-size: 0` on the container element the gaps will go away(make sure to reset the `font-size` on the inline-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, inline-block elements will display with the same automatic pseudo-margin spacing native to other inline objects.  Whereas floated elements are treated as completely independent in relation to the document's object flow (so, no annoying gaps).

Sorry I can't give a more detailed answer, but this is definitely something I've wrestled with before.  For what it's worth, the spacing should be *reliably* annoying for inline-block elements, you just have to remember to compensate for those *pseudo-margins* if you're trying to everything contained within a parent element without being pushed to the next line.